# Bootstrap 3: responsiveness issue as display size reduces

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've got a 2-column form, where each column contains multiple text inputs, made up as follows:

```
row
  left column, col-md-6
    row
      label, col-md-4: text inputs, col-md-8
  right column, col-md-6
    row
      label, col-md-4: text inputs, col-md-8
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eaaob8bn/). This looks good, with this output on a large screen:

[image]

And this output on a narrow screen:

[image]

So far so good - this is exactly what I want. The problem comes when the width of the text inputs in either column (the `col-md-8`) increases above some threshold. When this happens, the switch from a wide display to a narrow display is no longer clean, and produces this intermediate output as the display narrows:

[image]

This doesn't look good, and would need extra css to control the vertical spacing between `A` and `F`, and so on. You can trigger this by changing `size=2` to `size=3` for inputs `D` and `4` in the fiddle.

Any idea if I can fix/control this? Basically, I want the defined columns to stack: either the two `col-md-6` columns should stack on top of each other (image 2), or the `col-md-8` inputs should stack under the `col-md-4` labels. Instead, Bootstrap seems to have taken an alternative approach, which is breaking up content *inside* a column (image 3). This feels like the wrong thing to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like This You need right..**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/eaaob8bn/1/)**

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6'> 
        <div class='row'>
            <label class='col-md-3 control-label' for='myid1'>Label #1</label> 
            <div class='col-md-9'>
                <input type=text size=2 maxlength=2 value="A" disabled id='myid1'>
                <input type=text size=2 maxlength=2 value="B" disabled>
                <input type=text size=2 maxlength=2 value="C" disabled>
                <input type=text size=2 maxlength=2 value="D" disabled>
                <input type=text size=5 maxlength=5 value="E" disabled>
                <input type=text size=5 maxlength=5 value="F" disabled>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- 1st row in left column -->
    </div>     <!-- left column -->
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class='row'>
            <label class='col-md-3 control-label' for='myid2'>Label #2</label>
            <div class='col-md-9'>
                <input type=text size=2 maxlength=2 value="1" disabled id='myid2'>
                <input type=text size=2 maxlength=2 value="2" disabled>
                <input type=text size=2 maxlength=2 value="3" disabled>
                <input type=text size=2 maxlength=2 value="4" disabled>
                <input type=text size=5 maxlength=5 value="5" disabled>
                <input type=text size=5 maxlength=5 value="6" disabled>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- 1st row in right column -->
    </div>     <!-- right column -->
</div>         <!-- outer row -->
```

Comment: All you've done is change the label/input width split from `col-md-4`/`col-md-8` to `col-md-3`/`col-md-9`, so you've made the input column wider. This just puts off the problem; it doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<form action="#" class="form-horizontal">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Label#1</label>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input placeholder="A" class="form-control" type="text">

      </div><div class="col-xs-2">
      <input placeholder="B" class="form-control" type="text">

      </div><div class="col-xs-2">
      <input placeholder="C" class="form-control" type="text">

      </div><div class="col-xs-2">
      <input placeholder="D" class="form-control" type="text">

      </div><div class="col-xs-2">
      <input placeholder="E" class="form-control" type="text">

      </div>


  </div>

  </div></div>    

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Label#2</label>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input placeholder="1" class="form-control" type="text">

      </div><div class="col-xs-2">
      <input placeholder="2" class="form-control" type="text">

      </div><div class="col-xs-2">
      <input placeholder="3" class="form-control" type="text">

      </div><div class="col-xs-2">
      <input placeholder="4" class="form-control" type="text">

      </div><div class="col-xs-2">
      <input placeholder="5" class="form-control" type="text">

      </div>
  </div>

  </div></div>    
  </div>
</form>
```

**bootply** http://www.bootply.com/asBfmaPKqB

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think this really adresses the issue. The original has 6 input elements in a single column, and they have different sizes, and I want them to all stack together and flow as a single entity. However, your code splits all input elements  into  their own individual columns, so they're all completely independent, and fill up their own column, instead of all fitting together in a single column.

Comment: mean you want to full width column design on all screen options